# Trying to get property of non-object. Objects in php work on localhost but not on Hostingsite

Tags: php, localhost

I have just uploaded my CI project on a hosting site but now, whenever the script accesses a property of objects, they are no longer recognized as objects, therefore the property can't be accessed and used.
 I've tried `print_r($someobject)` and it works just fine. It shows me all the properties.
 But when i try to `print_r($someobject->property)` it no longer works. The message i get is:`Trying to get property of non-object.`

I've tried treating it as an array and it doesn't work either. Also, i don't know if it helps or not, but indexes of arrays don't work either on uploaded version.
For example, on localhost i was returning the result of a query that returned just one value: `q->result()[0]`. Now this doesn't work either, but if i take out the index(key) and leave `q->result()` it works.

Update: SO apparently all the objects that have values retrieved from a database work just fine as objects on localhost BUT when i upload the project on the hosting site (the same php version) the object is wrapped in an array on the first position. Anyone else ever experienced anything like this? Or have an idea of what might be going wrong?

eg. `on localhost:  $object->property === on hosting site: $object[0]->property.`

Comment: Try to post an code example

Comment: You should provide the response you get from print_r($someobject)

Answer (score 0):

Check the servers php version. syntax like `fun()[0]` only works in
late version of php. If version is the problem then assigning to a
variable first will solve the array case. like:

```
$temp = $o->fun();
$temp[0];
```

Regarding the Object property problem do var_dump($o) and look
at the type of the object. That should tell you what is wrong.

-edit-

Most database bindings have different fetch modes. The mode determine
if data is fetched as an object, as bindings to certain variables, as
arrays of objects or arrays of arrays etc. It might be worth investigating
for your particular binding library if there is a default mode, and if so
if that default could differ between hosting and local. Check the documentation
for your library and then compare the php ini files locally and on the hosting.

Comment: There is a diff in the php versions of the wamp and the host, but after 'var_dump($obj)'it still is not clear why i have this issue. returned :'array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#25 (14) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["name"]=>
    string(43) "Brisbane Int"
    ["size"]=>
    string(2) "32"
    ["year"]=>
    string(4) "2014"
    ["score"]=>
    NULL
    ["city"]=>
    string(8) "Brisbane"
  }
}' So when try to echo or print_r the '$obj->id' or other property i should get it, wouldn't u say? Instead, i get the trying to get property of non-object error.

Comment: The output tells you that `$obj` is an array with length 1, and the first (and only) element is an object with properties id, name, size ... etc. So you should be able to access it like `$obj[0]->id`

Comment: Yes, i interpret it like that, too. But i'm not looking to alter all my code (it would take a lot of time and effort). I was looking for a solution to having the same code work identically on both localhost and on the hosting site. How could i do that?

Comment: Well, you have to figure out why the variable is wrapped in an array on the hosting site but not locally. You will have to search backwards until you find the place where the values start to differ. Where or why that might be is not easy to guess based on the given information...